# Ubuntu Shortcut Menu opening spontaneously

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04, toshiba-laptop

About two days ago the shortcut menu started opening spontaneously and wont close for more than 2 seconds, making it impossible to type anything since most keys start working as shortcuts and others just won't work at all. Anyone know how to resolve this? I've re-installed Ubuntu already but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely the keyboard itself.

Try switching it out to see if the issue is corrected, and if so, you could try to look over the original keyboard to figure out if a key is stuck.

If you have the shortcut menu mapped to a key using `gnome-control-center keyboard` , that will give you a good idea of which keys are stuck. There is also the possibility that the keyboard is just bad, which depending on how high quality it is, could be a problem. Either way though, I can just about guarantee that this is your issue.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean, turn off the keyboard. It is weird because if I plug my USB keyboard it still does it, actually even the on screen keyboard gets stuck like that.